# Polygonal connected path proof

Tags: real-analysis

> If $G\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ is open then $G$ is connected iff G is
>   polygonally path-connected.

I am having trouble understanding the proof of this theorem.

> Proof:
>
> Assume $G$ is connected and choose any $x\in G$. Let$$\begin{cases} G_1=\{y\in
>  G:\text{y can be joined to x by a polygonal path contained in G}\} \\\\ G_2 =\{z\in G:\text{z cannot be joined to x by a polygonal
>  path contained in G}\}  \end{cases}$$ $(1)$ Note that $G_1\cup G_2=G\ \text{and}\ G_1\cap G_2 =\emptyset$.
>
> Choose $y\in G_1$ since $G$ is open. Since $G$ is
>   open, $\exists\ r>0$ such that $B_r(y)\subset G$. $(2)$ Choose $z\in
>  B_r(y)$; we must show $z\in G_1$. Let $P$ be the polygonal curve
>   joining $x$ to $y$.
>
> (3) Note $y$ is joined to $z$ by a line segment
>   $L$ lying in $G$, hence $P\cup L$ is a polygonal curve joining $x$ to
>   $z$. Hence $z \in G_1$ so $G_1$ is open. $(4)$ Claim $G_2$ is open,
>   thus $(G_1,G_2)$ is a disconnection of $G$ if $G_1,G_2\ne \emptyset$.
>   Hence one of $G_1,G_2$ must be empty which is $G_2 =\emptyset$ since
>   $x\in G_1$.

For $(1)$, why is $G_1\cap G_2 =\emptyset$, aren't we suppose to show that it is connected thus it can't be disjoint? For $(2)$, we are able to let $z \in B_r(y)$ because of the fact it is **open**, correct? For $(3)$ why is there a line segment joining $x$ to $z$; in the conditions it says that $z$ cannot be joined to $x$? And $(4)$, why is it a disconnection if $G_1,G_2\ne \emptyset$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) By definition, $G_2=G\setminus G_1,$ so they are disjoint.

(2) No. We can choose $z\in B_r(y)$ because it is non-empty. We are trying to show that $G_1$ is open by showing that for each $y\in G_1$ there is an open ball around $y$ contained in $G_1$. Knowing that $G$ is open allows us to pick a candidate ball.

(3) We can only conclude that $z$ can't be connected to $x$ if $z\in G_2$. Simply calling a point "$z$" isn't enough to conclude that it lies in $G_2$. If it's confusing you, define $$G_2=\{w\in G:w\text{ cannot be joined to }x\text{ by a polygonal path contained in }G\}$$ instead, and proceed with the rest of the proof in the same way.

(4) A disconnection of $G$ is two non-empty disjoint open sets whose union is $G$. The proof showed that they were both open, and were disjoint, and that their union was $G$. Hence, they are a disconnection if they are both non-empty.

Comment: I understand $1$ and $4$ now, but I still dont understand $2$ and $3$, more so $2$.

Comment: For (3), note that we can join $z$ to $y$ with a line segment $L$ lying in $B_r(y),$ since $z\in B_r(y).$ As $B_r(y)\subseteq G$, then $L\subseteq G$, and since $P\subseteq G$ (by choice of $P$, which choice is possible since $y\in G_1$), then....

Comment: As for (2), note that $B_r(y)\subseteq G$ turned out to be enough to ensure that we could connect any point in $B_r(y)$ to $x$ with a polygonal path. Think on it, and let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I understand $3$ now, but $2$ is still confusing. Why are we allowed to pick $z\in B_r(y)$? Is it because since $z\in G$ and $B_r(y)\subset G$?

Comment: There exists $z\in B_r(y)$ because $B_r(y)=\{z\in\Bbb R^p:d(y,z)<r\}$ is non-empty--after all, $y\in B_r(y)$, since $r>0$. We need to show that **all** elements of $B_r(y)$ are elements of $G_1,$ so we choose one arbitrarily. $B_r(y)\subseteq G$ (so $z\in G$) allows us to complete step (3), together with the fact that $y\in G_1$ (see my first comment).

Comment: Ohh, I understand now. When you said, "we need to show that all elements of $B_r (y)$ are elements of $G_1$" it made it clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.