# Is the closure of an open connected set polygonally connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

In an arbitrary metric space, I know that connected does not imply polygonally connected.
However, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, [an open connected set is connected iff it is polygonally connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340351/polygonal-connected-path-proof).

Is the last statement also true for the closure of an open connected set? I suspect not. Can someone provide a simple, intuitive counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the connected open set $$U=\{\,(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<4, (x-1)^2+y^2>1\,\}.$$
It's closure contains $(2,0)$ and there is no polygon leading away from it: Any line segment starting there leaves the outer or enters the inner circle.

(For a *simply* connected example, consider the upper half of $U$ only)

Comment: This is really neat.